# TypeScript error on <Text> for native paper

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-native-paper

A while ago all my `<Text>` components started giving TypeScript errors for missing attributes (`onPressIn` and `onPressOut`). Now, I would prefer not to add all these attributes with undefined values to all my `<Text>` components.

How do I fix this? And are these attributes suddenly required?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there's a typing problem with `react-native-paper`, you can check the issue [here](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/2965)

Use these latest packages to remove the error based on the:

```
react-native-paper 4.10.1
react-native 0.66.3
@types/react-native 0.66.4
```

here is the link to the [solution](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/2965#issuecomment-971418306)